# How to allow only dd/mm/yyyy date input format using jquery?

Tags: jquery, date

I am designing a web form, whereby I want to allow users to only input dates in the format `DD/MM/YYYY`.

I've tried with the following code to show an error message if the date is not valid, however if I add something like `5/5/5`, it still passes is as a valid value.

```
$('#DateB').blur(function(){
    var s= $('#DateB').val();
    var dateRegex = '^(0[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](19|20)\d\d$';
    if(!dateRegex.match(s)){
        $("#msgDOB").val("date format not valid");
        $("#msgDate").css("display","block");
    }else
    {
        $("#msgDate").css("display","none");
    }
});
```

Anyone can please help me fine-tune this code?

Comment: why don't you use `input[type="date"]` or just use something like datepicker widget from jquery ui. as you are using jQuery.

Comment: As a side remark, if this is so important for you you will need to validate user input also server-side. Any client-side validation is just for user-friendlyness, data-integrity is tackled on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this regex:

```
/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$/
```

And if you are simply using textbox then try to use jquery masking. I t will help you in avoiding this type of validations.

To learn about jquery masking [click here](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

Comment: Will it work with datepicker too?

Answer (score 1):

Try this regexp:

```
^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

you can test it for example on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/xX7dR0/1)